# How do you paste a multiline string into .editor mode?

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop, node-repl

I've got a SQL string that I'd like to run a regex against. I can't get it to paste correctly.

```
> .editor
// Entering editor mode (Ctrl+D to finish, Ctrl+C to cancel)
s="with docs as (
    SELECT
        \"documentNumber\""

// (press Ctrl D here) 

s="with docs as (
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

The first line works fine outside of .editor mode

```
> s="with docs as ("
'with docs as ('

> process.version
'v20.9.0'
```

How do you paste a multiline string into the .editor mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use it with `` instead of "". It will not throw an error like the above. For example-

```
s=`with docs as (
    SELECT
        \"documentNumber\"`
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: That worked. Thought I tried that!